# Cant get select2 to work with form post to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

I tried to get this to work but am stumped can someone help me figure out what I did wrong ?

Debugger says no errors. I cant get other form in to work. I am trying to get the form from my jsfiddle to post onto the other page for storage.

This is the php file into which I am trying to POST/store the data.

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <title>Please Sign In</title>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles/form.css?v3.1.1414"/>    


  <style type='text/css'>
    .selectContainer {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 200px;
    }
    .form-label{
        width:1500px !important;
    }
    .form-label-left{
        width:1500px !important;
    }
    .form-line{
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }
    .form-label-right{
        width:1500px !important;
    }
    .form-all{
        width:1500px;
        background:#800080;
        color:#000000 !important;
        font-family:'Courier New';
        font-size:45px;
    }
</style>

<script src="js/prototype.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/json2.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/protoplus.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/protoplus-ui.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jotform.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/calendarview.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   JotForm.init(function(){
      JotForm.setCalendar("7", false);
      JotForm.displayLocalTime("hour_7", "min_7", "ampm_7");
      $('input_42').hint('ex: myname@example.com');
      $('input_19').hint('01/01');
   });
</script>

<form class="jotform-form" name="input" action="www.vumiche.com/clients/clients.php" method="post" name="Signinform">
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $('#e1').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Haircut Woman'}, {id:1, text:'Haircut Men'}, {id:2, text:'Haircut Children'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:4, text:'Hair Coloring'}, 
                    {id:5, text:'Tinting Semi/Permanent'}, {id:6, text:'Full Weave'}, {id:7, text:'Cap Frost'}, {id:8, text:'Partial Highlights/Lowlights'}, {id:9, text:'Single Foil'}, 
                    {id:10, text:'Color Gloss'}, {id:11, text:'Color Remove'}, {id:12, text:'Color Corrective'}, {id:13, text:'Reconstruction'}, {id:14, text:'Hair Styling'}, 
                    {id:15, text:'Shampoo and Style'}, {id:16, text:'Updo'}, {id:17, text:'Wedding Updo'}, {id:18, text:'Straightening'}, {id:19, text:'Deep Conditiong'}, 
                    {id:20, text:'Hair Texture'}, {id:21, text:'Inventive Perms'}, {id:21, text:'Body Waves'}, {id:22, text:'Hair Straightening'}, {id:23, text:'Chemical Straightening'}, 
                    {id:24, text:'Japanese Straightening'}, {id:25, text:'Karatin Blowout'}, {id:26, text:'Karatin Treatment'}, {id:27, text:'Hair Extension '}, 
                    {id:1, text:'Hair Extension Weaving'}, {id:2, text:'Single Hair Extension'}, {id:28, text:'Feather Hair Extension'}, {id:29, text:'Sparkle Extension'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e2').select2({
            data: [ {id:1, text:'Gel Manicure'}, {id:1, text:'Gel Pedicure'}, {id:2, text:'Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Sea Salt Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Deluxe Manicure'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Reflexology Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Express Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Spa Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Spa Pedicure w/Sea Salt'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Deluxe Spa Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Detox Foot Spa'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        }); 

        $('#e3').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Gel Full Set'}, {id:1, text:'Gel Fill'}, {id:2, text:'Gel Color'}, {id:3, text:'Silk Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Silk Fill'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Acrylic Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Acrylic Fill'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Fill'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Pink & White Fill'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Paraffin Wax'}, {id:3, text:'Nail Art'}, {id:3, text:'3D Nail Art'}, {id:3, text:'French'}, {id:3, text:'Hand Polish Change'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });


        $('#e4').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Derm Renew Facial'}, {id:1, text:'Thermo Plastic Facial'}, {id:2, text:'Algomask +Cooling Thermo'}, {id:3, text:'Corrective Mask Facial'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Collagen 90'}, {id:3, text:'Sea C Spa'}, {id:1, text:'Botinol “Botox like Effect”'}, {id:2, text:'Micro-Dermabrasion Treatment'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Home Facial'}, {id:3, text:'European Facial'}, {id:3, text:'Dark Eye Circle & Puffiness'}, {id:3, text:'Acne Treatment Facial'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Chemical Peel Treatment'}, {id:3, text:'Skin Tags, Brown Spot'}, {id:3, text:'Freckle, Mole Removal'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e5').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Eyebrow'}, {id:1, text:'Lip'}, {id:2, text:'Chin'}, {id:3, text:'Freckle, Mole Removal'}, {id:3, text:'Face'}, {id:3, text:'Half Legs'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Full Legs'}, {id:3, text:'Under Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Half Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Full Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Bikini'}, {id:3, text:'Brazilian'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Stomach'}, {id:3, text:'Back'}, {id:3, text:'Shoulder'}, {id:3, text:'Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Neck'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e6').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Body Bronzing'}, {id:1, text:'Full Legs Bronzing'}, {id:2, text:'Sparkle Extension'}
            ],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e7').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Bridal Make-Up'}, {id:1, text:'Make-Up Application'}, {id:2, text:'Lash or Brow Tinting'}, {id:3, text:'Eye Lash Perm'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Flare Eye Lash Extension'}, {id:3, text:'Single Lash Extension'}, {id:3, text:'Airbrush Make-Up'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e8').select2({
            data: [{id:0, text:'30 Minutes'}, {id:1, text:'60 Minutes'}, {id:2, text:'90'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e9').select2({
            data: [{id:2, text:'15 Minutes'}, {id:0, text:'30 Minutes'}, {id:1, text:'60 Minutes'}, {id:2, text:'90 Minutes'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e10').select2({
            data: [{id:0, text:'1 Session'}, {id:1, text:'3 or More Sessions'}, {id:2, text:'6 or More Session'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e11').select2({
            data: [{id:0, text:'1 Session'}, {id:1, text:'3 or More Sessions'}, {id:2, text:'6 or More Session'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        $('#e12').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Eyebrow'}, {id:1, text:'Eyebrow Hair Stroke'}, {id:2, text:'Eye Liner'}, {id:3, text:'Eye Liner Upper & Lower'}, 
                    {id:4, text:'Lip Liner'}, {id:5, text:'FUll Lip'}, {id:6, text:'COrrective'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });


    });

</script>

</form>

</head>


<body>


<?php
  if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
  {
    $clients.php = $_POST['www.vumiche.com/clients/clients.php'];
  }
?>

<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="32276820656155" />
  <div class="form-all">
    <ul class="form-section">
      <li id="cid_1" class="form-input-wide">
        <div class="form-header-group">
          <h1 id="header_1" class="form-header">
            Please sign in.
          </h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line form-line-column form-line-column-clear" id="id_3">
        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_3" for="input_3">
          First Name<span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_3" class="form-input-wide">
          <input type="text" class=" form-textbox validate[required]" data-type="input-textbox" id="input_3" name="q3_firstName" size="110" value="" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_4">
        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_4" for="input_4">
          Last Name<span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_4" class="form-input-wide">
          <input type="text" class=" form-textbox validate[required]" data-type="input-textbox" id="input_4" name="q4_lastName4" size="110" value="" maxlength="50" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_6">
        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_6" for="input_6">
          Phone Number<span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_6" class="form-input-wide"><span class="form-sub-label-container"><input class="form-textbox validate[required]" type="tel" name="q6_phoneNumber[area]" id="input_6_area" size="3">
            -
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="input_6_area" id="sublabel_area"> 

Area Code </label></span><span class="form-sub-label-container"><input class="form-textbox validate[required]" type="tel" name="q6_phoneNumber[phone]" id="input_6_phone" size="8">
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="input_6_phone" id="sublabel_phone"> 

Phone Number </label></span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_7">
        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_7" for="input_7">
          Date<span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_7" class="form-input-wide"><span class="form-sub-label-container"><input class="form-textbox validate[required]" id="month_7" name="q7_date7[month]" type="tel" size="2" maxlength="2" value="09" /><span class="date-separate">&nbsp;/</span>
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="month_7" id="sublabel_month"> Month 

</label></span><span class="form-sub-label-container"><input class="form-textbox validate[required]" id="day_7" name="q7_date7[day]" type="tel" size="2" maxlength="2" value="30" /><span class="date-separate">&nbsp;/</span>
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="day_7" id="sublabel_day"> Day 

</label></span><span class="form-sub-label-container">

<input class="form-textbox validate[required]" id="year_7" name="q7_date7[year]" type="tel" size="4" maxlength="4" value="2013" />
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="year_7" id="sublabel_year"> Year 

</label></span><span style='white-space: nowrap;'><span class="form-sub-label-container"><div id="at_7">
                at
              </div>

  <div class="selectContainer">
    <p>
        <label for="e1">Hair Service</label>
        <input name="hair" width="25" type="text" id="e1" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="e2">Nails Service</label>
        <input name="nails" width="25" type="text" id="e2" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="e3">Specialized Nails</label>
        <input name="Special" width="25" type="text" id="e3" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
     <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e4">Skin Care</label>
        <input name="Skin" width="25" type="text" id="e4" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
         <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e5">Face & Body Waxing</label>
        <input name="Waxing" width="25" type="text" id="e5" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
         <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e6">Body Bronzing</label>
        <input name="Bronzing" width="25" type="text" id="e6" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="e7">Cosmetic</label>
        <input name="Cosmetic" width="25" type="text" id="e7" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="e8">Massage</label>
        <input name="Massage" width="25" type="text" id="e8" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="e9">Slimming & Toning Stomach Treatment</label>
        <input name="Slimming" width="25" type="text" id="e9" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
     <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e10">Body Wrap</label>
        <input name="Wrap" width="25" type="text" id="e10" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
         <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e11">Double Chin</label>
        <input name="Chin" width="25" type="text" id="e11" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
         <BR>
     <p>
        <label for="e12">Permanent Make-Up Tattooing</label>
        <input name="Tattooing" width="25" type="text" id="e12" placeholder="Select all that apply" />
    </p>
    <br/>
</div>

</body>


</html>

</pre>
```

And here is a jsfiddle of how the page displays http://jsfiddle.net/slow503/5sHe7/embedded/result/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this line: "I cant get other form in to work."

Comment: What is the state of this problem right now? Do you have it solved? If not, please update your answer to tell us exactly what you need (read your question as if you were a stranger with no idea what the POSTer is doing or what the problem is). And *please upvote any answer that has been helpful to you.* Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using jQuery along with Prototypejs, and that is creating a conflict in your script.  Please check [this](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) or [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to ignore the conflict.

Try this:

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <title>Please Sign In</title>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict(); // change#1 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles/form.css?v3.1.1414"/>    


  <style type='text/css'>
    .selectContainer {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 200px;
    }
    .form-label{
        width:1500px !important;
    }
    .form-label-left{
        width:1500px !important;
    }
    .form-line{
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
    }
    .form-label-right{
        width:1500px !important;
    }
    .form-all{
        width:1500px;
        background:#800080;
        color:#000000 !important;
        font-family:'Courier New';
        font-size:45px;
    }
</style>

<script src="js/prototype.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/json2.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/protoplus.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/protoplus-ui.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jotform.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/calendarview.js?v=3.1.1586" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   JotForm.init(function(){
      JotForm.setCalendar("7", false);
      JotForm.displayLocalTime("hour_7", "min_7", "ampm_7");
      $('input_42').hint('ex: myname@example.com');
      $('input_19').hint('01/01');
   });
</script>

<form class="jotform-form" name="input" action="www.vumiche.com/clients/clients.php" method="post" name="Signinform">
<script type='text/javascript'>
// change 2 replace $ with jQuery in following code
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#e1').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Haircut Woman'}, {id:1, text:'Haircut Men'}, {id:2, text:'Haircut Children'}, {id:3, text:'Hair Trim Bang or Neck'}, {id:4, text:'Hair Coloring'}, 
                    {id:5, text:'Tinting Semi/Permanent'}, {id:6, text:'Full Weave'}, {id:7, text:'Cap Frost'}, {id:8, text:'Partial Highlights/Lowlights'}, {id:9, text:'Single Foil'}, 
                    {id:10, text:'Color Gloss'}, {id:11, text:'Color Remove'}, {id:12, text:'Color Corrective'}, {id:13, text:'Reconstruction'}, {id:14, text:'Hair Styling'}, 
                    {id:15, text:'Shampoo and Style'}, {id:16, text:'Updo'}, {id:17, text:'Wedding Updo'}, {id:18, text:'Straightening'}, {id:19, text:'Deep Conditiong'}, 
                    {id:20, text:'Hair Texture'}, {id:21, text:'Inventive Perms'}, {id:21, text:'Body Waves'}, {id:22, text:'Hair Straightening'}, {id:23, text:'Chemical Straightening'}, 
                    {id:24, text:'Japanese Straightening'}, {id:25, text:'Karatin Blowout'}, {id:26, text:'Karatin Treatment'}, {id:27, text:'Hair Extension '}, 
                    {id:1, text:'Hair Extension Weaving'}, {id:2, text:'Single Hair Extension'}, {id:28, text:'Feather Hair Extension'}, {id:29, text:'Sparkle Extension'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e2').select2({
            data: [ {id:1, text:'Gel Manicure'}, {id:1, text:'Gel Pedicure'}, {id:2, text:'Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Sea Salt Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Deluxe Manicure'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Reflexology Manicure'}, {id:3, text:'Express Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Spa Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Spa Pedicure w/Sea Salt'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Deluxe Spa Pedicure'}, {id:3, text:'Detox Foot Spa'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        }); 

        jQuery('#e3').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Gel Full Set'}, {id:1, text:'Gel Fill'}, {id:2, text:'Gel Color'}, {id:3, text:'Silk Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Silk Fill'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Acrylic Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Acrylic Fill'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Full Set'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Fill'}, {id:3, text:'Solar Pink & White Fill'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Paraffin Wax'}, {id:3, text:'Nail Art'}, {id:3, text:'3D Nail Art'}, {id:3, text:'French'}, {id:3, text:'Hand Polish Change'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });


        jQuery('#e4').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Derm Renew Facial'}, {id:1, text:'Thermo Plastic Facial'}, {id:2, text:'Algomask +Cooling Thermo'}, {id:3, text:'Corrective Mask Facial'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Collagen 90'}, {id:3, text:'Sea C Spa'}, {id:1, text:'Botinol Ԃotox like Effectԧ}, {id:2, text:'Micro-Dermabrasion Treatment'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Home Facial'}, {id:3, text:'European Facial'}, {id:3, text:'Dark Eye Circle & Puffiness'}, {id:3, text:'Acne Treatment Facial'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Chemical Peel Treatment'}, {id:3, text:'Skin Tags, Brown Spot'}, {id:3, text:'Freckle, Mole Removal'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e5').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Eyebrow'}, {id:1, text:'Lip'}, {id:2, text:'Chin'}, {id:3, text:'Freckle, Mole Removal'}, {id:3, text:'Face'}, {id:3, text:'Half Legs'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Full Legs'}, {id:3, text:'Under Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Half Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Full Arms'}, {id:3, text:'Bikini'}, {id:3, text:'Brazilian'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Stomach'}, {id:3, text:'Back'}, {id:3, text:'Shoulder'}, {id:3, text:'Neck'}, {id:3, text:'Neck'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e6').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Body Bronzing'}, {id:1, text:'Full Legs Bronzing'}, {id:2, text:'Sparkle Extension'}
            ],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e7').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Bridal Make-Up'}, {id:1, text:'Make-Up Application'}, {id:2, text:'Lash or Brow Tinting'}, {id:3, text:'Eye Lash Perm'}, 
                    {id:3, text:'Flare Eye Lash Extension'}, {id:3, text:'Single Lash Extension'}, {id:3, text:'Airbrush Make-Up'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e8').select2({
            data: [{id:0, text:'30 Minutes'}, {id:1, text:'60 Minutes'}, {id:2, text:'90'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e9').select2({
            data: [{id:2, text:'15 Minutes'}, {id:0, text:'30 Minutes'}, {id:1, text:'60 Minutes'}, {id:2, text:'90 Minutes'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e10').select2({
            data: [{id:0, text:'1 Session'}, {id:1, text:'3 or More Sessions'}, {id:2, text:'6 or More Session'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e11').select2({
            data: [{id:0, text:'1 Session'}, {id:1, text:'3 or More Sessions'}, {id:2, text:'6 or More Session'}],
            multiple: true
        });

        jQuery('#e12').select2({
            data: [ {id:0, text:'Eyebrow'}, {id:1, text:'Eyebrow Hair Stroke'}, {id:2, text:'Eye Liner'}, {id:3, text:'Eye Liner Upper & Lower'}, 
                    {id:4, text:'Lip Liner'}, {id:5, text:'FUll Lip'}, {id:6, text:'COrrective'}
                    ],
            multiple: true
        });


    });

</script>
```

Comment: @Abhisheki have no idea what to do with that code to be honest. where do I put it? its all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `<form>` tags surrounding the javascript/jQuery. Those tags need to be surrounding the HTML markup.

Move the `<form>` tags into the markup, wrapping all elements with `name=` attributes that will be included in the form.

Comment: I I am trying to get the forms without select2 to load and function but they wont even show at all.